# Web service calls another web service on same host

Tags: c#, web-services, http

I am currently looking at maintaining some code when I noticed that a web service call was making another web service call on the same box. So web service A was calling web service B using the host localhost.

Not sure why the developer did this and I was wondering apart from twice the number of calls being made what are the implications on the web server (performance/memory/thread pool etc) of the web service working in this way?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the other web service is deployed as part of a separate web application. Of course two web applications will take up more resources than one.  However, iis/asp.net are designed to serve multiple applications.

The code is on the same server,  I can see why you'd want to call it natively (mostly for the sake of performance). However , I can think of many very good reasons why the developer chose to expose the functionality as a web service.

Perhaps the separate service isn't being developed along with the client application, by other people, under a different release schedule (or perhaps it's a third party service).  It's much easier to update a single deployment unit vs all the applications that might make use of it.

Having the functionality in a separate service/deployable unit also allows that service to be scaled separately from the consuming application.

His/her approach might fall nicely in line with the reasoning behind micro-service based architecture where full stack services that do just one thing are deployed separately and then orchestrated to make an application.

But then again none of that might apply and it may just be a case of bone-headedness of laziness.  It's up to you to decide.

Comment: Thanks, some really good points. I mentioned below that there are endpoints that use the call to B and if there is not a big performance hit to localhost the design makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> web service A was calling web service B using the host localhost.

That's not a good design rather the second call should be made local. That is like below which will end up having only one call made and so making only one round trip but in your actual case making two separate calls which will end up having double round trips over the network.

```
[webMethod]
public string A(string arg)
{
  //Some business logic processing;
  B(arg);

  //Some more processing and return data;
}

 public void B(string arg)
 {
   // do some internal logic;
 }
```

Comment: It is _possible_ that Service B is also called from remote locations.  In which case the design makes sense.  The expense of a local web service call is trivial compared to network latency and it is better than having two versions of the same function (one for local calls and  one for remote calls).

Comment: @SteveWellens, that's possible and yes we can make `B()` as well a `WebMethod` but I think in this particular case, where A() is calling B(); having the service method call B() locally would make much more sense than calling it over the proxy channel.

Comment: As I pointed out, that adds complexity because you would have two versions of the same function (one for local calls and one for remote calls) or you would be adding another layer of code for an insignificant performance gain.  Calls to the localhost do not go out into the network.

Comment: @SteveWellens: Thanks for you reply. I re-checked the code and looked at all the endpoints (client) and they did call B. You mentioned call to localhost do not go out into the network which I guess will not mean two round trips?

Comment: @JD., Since you already clarified that  `B()` do have a remote call then your design actually makes sense and since it's localhost, network performance won't be a big hit.

Comment: Thank you Rahul. Also as Robert above mentioned if we now move services to other hosts it is possible without redesign.

Comment: @JD., Yes it's. I made the answer keeping in mind that `B()` is local and have no remote call but since you confirmed that `B()` is also a operation contract then what Steven Wellens said makes much sense to me.